# Create document-term matrix from dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, matrix, corpus

I'm trying to pre-process a text file, where each line is a bi-gram words of a document with their frequency in that document. here is an example of each line:

i_like 1  you_know 2  ....  not_good 1

I managed to create the dictionary from the whole corpus.
Now I want to read the corpus line by line and having the dictionary, create the document-term matrix so each element (i,j) in matrix will be the frequency of term "j" in document "i".

Comment: I am not sure I understand, where are the names of the documents? Or is there a text file for each document?

Comment: Each line of the text file represents a document.(So, the whole text file is a corpus) And the format that each document is presented,is what I wrote in the example above. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that generates an integer index for each word using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, int> m_WordIndexes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

int GetWordIndex(string word)
{
  int result;
  if (!m_WordIndexes.TryGet(word, out result)) {
    result = m_WordIndexes.Count;
    m_WordIndexes.Add(word, result);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The result matrix is:

```
List<List<int>> m_Matrix = new List<List<int>>();
```

Processing each line of the text file generates one row of the matrix:

```
List<int> ProcessLine(string line)
{
  List<int> result = new List<int>();
  . . . split the line in a sequence of word / number of occurences . . . 
  . . . for each word / number of occurences . . .{
    int index = GetWordIndex(word);      
    while (index > result.Count) {
      result.Add(0);
    }  
    result.Insert(index, numberOfOccurences);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Your read the text file one line at a time, calling `ProcessLine()` on each line and adding the resulting list to m_Matrix.

Comment: Thank you MiMo, in fact the dictionary is too big and I decided to create the sparse matrix to be efficient, but i used the idea behind your solution. Thanks